# Discriminator formula involving referenced table and not main class table

Tags: java, hibernate, discriminator

I have hibernate XML where I'd like to retrieve a row as an instance of the subclass based on the results of a discriminator formula. Trouble is, the field to examine is on a referenced table, not on the table itself. My object is a merchant-user account, which is a combination of user account and merchant. The user_account table has a role field that may include several values, of which a few indicate a level of admin permissions. I'd like to do something like this, but this itself (trying to reference `userAccount.role` in the case statement) does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.rc.model.mexp.MerchantUserAccount" table="merchant_user_account">
        <id name="merchantUserAcctId" type="int">
            <column name="merchantuseracctid" scale="10" precision="0" not-null="true" unique="true" sql-type="int unsigned"/>
            <generator class="com.rc.model.jdbc.sequence.MexpIdentifierGenerator">
                <param name="sequence">seq_merchantuseraccountid</param>
                <param name="idDataType">int</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <discriminator formula="case when userAccount.role in (2, 3, 4, 5) then '1' else '0' end" type="boolean"/>

        <many-to-one name="userAccount" class="com.rc.model.user.security.UserAccount" column="userid"
                     unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>

        <many-to-one name="merchantAccount" class="com.rc.model.mexp.MerchantAccount" column="merchantacctid"
                     not-null="true" cascade="all"/>

        <subclass name="com.rc.model.mexp.AdminMerchantUserAccount" discriminator-value="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Is this even possible?